# How to pass the initial value for a binding property?

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
struct MyView: View {

@State var fieldValue = 0

init(fieldValue:Int) {
  self.fieldValue = fieldValue
}

var numberProxy: Binding<String> {
  Binding<String>(
    get: {
      String(fieldValue)
    },
    set: {
      fieldValue = Int($0) ?? 0
    }
  )
}

var body: some View {
    TextField("", text: numberProxy,
              onEditingChanged: { status in

              },
              onCommit:{
                
              })
}
```

I call tis from another view with:

```
MyView(200)
```

but MyView always shows 0

How do I make the passed value show on what is a binding property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `init` is basically a dead end but it seems to be what you are asking for

```
struct MyViewParent: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //You will never receive anything back with this init
            MyView(200)
        }
    }
}
struct MyView: View {
    //State is a source of truth it will never relay something to a previous View
    @State var fieldValue: Int //= 0 //Another init - Apple recommended
    ///Not a good way to init
    init(_ fieldValue:Int) {
        //You can init State here but there is no connection with the previous View
        //This is not recommended per Apple documentation State should only accessed from a View body
        //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state
        self._fieldValue = State(initialValue: fieldValue)
    }
    
    //Binding is a 2-way connection
    //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding
    var numberProxy: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get: {
                String(fieldValue)
            },
            set: {
                fieldValue = Int($0) ?? 0
            }
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //Shows that your proxy updates the State
            //Resets if a letter is put into the textfield.
            Text(fieldValue.description)
            TextField("", text: numberProxy, onEditingChanged: { status in  }, onCommit:{ })
        }
    }
}
```

With this `init` you get the changes

```
struct MyViewParent: View {
    @State var value: Int = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //Receives the changes from MyView
            Text(value.description)
            MyView(fieldValue: $value)
        }
    }
}
struct MyView: View {
    //Binding is a 2-way connection
    @Binding var fieldValue: Int 

    //Binding is a 2-way connection
    //https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/binding
    var numberProxy: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get: {
                String(fieldValue)
            },
            set: {
                fieldValue = Int($0) ?? 0
            }
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //Shows that your proxy updates this View's Binding and parent State
            //Resets to 0if a letter is put into the textfield.
            Text(fieldValue.description)
            TextField("", text: numberProxy, onEditingChanged: { status in  }, onCommit:{ })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If my way is not recommended, can you please explain how is the correct way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is all detailed in the comments on the code. The first way is just a dead end and the second way (Apple’s way) allows for the changes to be returned to the parent View. Both samples work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `State(initialValue:)`.

```
struct MyViewTest55: View {
    
    @State private var fieldValue = 0
    
    init(fieldValue: Int) {
        self._fieldValue = State(initialValue: fieldValue)
    }
    
    var numberProxy: Binding<String> {
        Binding<String>(
            get: {
                String(fieldValue)
            },
            set: {
                fieldValue = Int($0) ?? 0
            }
        )
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: numberProxy,
                  onEditingChanged: { status in
                    
                  },
                  onCommit:{
                    
                  })
    }
}
```